# What is the alternate of python's dir() in Java?

Tags: java, python, methods

While learning java through an online course, I came across type conversions using helper classes. Eg:

```
double d = 5.99;
double do = new Double(d);
int i = do.intvalue();
```

However they doesn't explain how can I find the methods like `do.intvalue()` if I am unaware of the existing methods. In Python, I can do a `dir(do)` and it would list all the methods. How can I check the same in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javap for the same.

```
javap java.lang.Double | grep -i int
public static final int MAX_EXPONENT;
public static final int MIN_EXPONENT;
public static final int SIZE;
public int intValue();
public int hashCode();
public int compareTo(java.lang.Double);
public static int compare(double, double);
```

public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);

For eg. If you see `System.out.println()`, but wondering what else could be available, you can always check

```
javap -c java.lang.System | grep -i out
public static final java.io.PrintStream out;
public static void setOut(java.io.PrintStream);
   4: invokestatic  #4                  // Method setOut0:(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V
   8: putstatic     #98                 // Field out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

and then do `javap java.io.PrintStream`